Display the category name over grouped products by category on WooCommerce shop page
I'm having hard time trying to display the category names above grouped products by category in WooCommerce shop page.
I tried using the code posted 10 years ago, and what suggested there, didn't really work.
The below code came close:
function wpa89819_wc_single_product(){

    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

    if ( $product_cats && ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ){

        $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats ); ?>

        <h2 itemprop="name" class="product_category_title"><span><?php echo $single_cat->name; ?></span></h2>

<?php }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'wpa89819_wc_single_product', 5 ); 

However it displays category name under each and every product.
Here is a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve:

I'd appreciate any help I can get.

"However it displays category name under each and every product." - that's because the woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook is inside each single product "wrapper", see https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/

Not sure if there is a proper way to do this with the default template, because that "grouping" doesn't appear to actually exist in there. The products are simply ordered by category. You might need to create your own template, in which you can implement a proper control break.
